# Extracting data from multidimensional NSMutableArray into a simpler array

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I'm learning iOS but have an issue extracting data from a multidimensional `NSMutableArray`, I've looked at various solutions but have not yet found one..

I have an `NSMutableArray` like

```
{
 "service_0" = {
    "name" = "name1";
    "description" = "description1";
};
 "service_2" = {
    "name" = "name2";
    "description" = "description2";
};
Etc...
}
```

I wish to extract data into a new `NSMutableArray` (or `NSArray`) to get the following output for use in text labels such as = `[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`

```
(
    name1,
    name2,
Etc...
)
```

What would be the best solution? Thanks

Comment: This looks more like a dictionary of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that is an array of dictionaries, unlike in the question...

```
NSArray *newArray = [oldArray valueForKeypath:@"name"];
```

You can make it mutable using `mutableCopy`, if you wish.

Comment: Your title and text refer to an array of dictionaries :-)

Comment: Handling a dictionary of dictionaries is far more problematic, and needs a few more lines of code (as in your answer).  `[[dictionary allValues] valueForKeypath:@"name"]` would work, however.

Comment: Thanks guys, for the quick responses! .. I changed the array to a dictionary as suggested and extracted the rows using .. [[[myArray allValues] valueForKeyPath:@"name"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];